# Using RestSharp on IOS Xamarin Monotouch

Tags: xamarin, restsharp

I am working on a project on Yammer Integration with our mobile product (IOS - C# Xamarin Monotouch). The underlying technique is integration using Yammer Rest Calls. For that purpose we are using RestSharp.

The call to the REST Service is pretty straight
Create a RestClient object
Create a RestSharp.RestRequest
Execute the request using the rest client

However i am see that on the IPAD the call to REST service takes about 5 -6 seconds average. The IPAD is using an open network. The same call in a windows application using rest sharp and .Net is fast.

Any clues? Anyone encountered the same issue with RestSharp performance on IOS.

Regards
Sid

Comment: Are the responses large? Serialization and deserialization of JSON/XML is fairly slow on iOS devices compared to desktop.

Comment: The responses are not that large. I am doing a get. And i believe the slowdown is not even at the point of de-serialization. I have logs before and after i execute the request and expense seems to be the call. I then use Newtonsoft JSON to convert the JSON response to a C# object which is fairly quick.

Comment: Have you tested how long it would take WebClient to execute the GET?

Comment: I have tried using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse in a small sample application but no effect. It still is the same. However if use  NSUrlConnection.Start with a connection delegate class i can see a huge difference. However if i go down that path how can i try to make this call synchronous. New to this so breaking my head.

Comment: See below for a sample HttpClient implementation. It is similar in functionality to RestSharp but doesn't embed JSON serializer. You can easily modify it to synchronous calls although I would recommended using asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sample Json client using HttpClient:

https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/Core/SimplyMobile.Web/JsonClient.cs

You would need to pass it a HttpClient and for this you can use ModernHttpClient from the Component Store which uses native HTTP implementation: http://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient

Plug in also your JSON serialize if you want to use the class as-is, they are found from the Plugins folder. For iOS there are the usual suspects; Json.NET, ServiceStack.Text and also your standard MS runtime serializer. ServiceStack is fastest of the serializers.

EDIT: Since this was upvoted I would like to add that there is now XLabs.Web component on NuGet that I based on this earlier source code. Works with the XLabs.Serialization serializers.